# Big spike in "Invalid Http Host Header" error messages - should I be worried?

Tags: django, security, amazon-web-services

So I've had a django app running on AWS for a couple of months now, just a small database project for my work - internal use for a small group. Ever since I got it set up, I've been getting those "Invalid HTTP Host Header" emails. After googling around about them, I decided to ignore them. Most of the IP addresses were going back to Amazon servers, which seemed legit, but as the site was working fine without them, I didn't see any reason to whitelist those IPs. Occasionally I would get an obvious nefarious attempt to connect, and was glad that everything seemed to be working fine in stopping the attempt.

However, as of about 7 PM today I've had a huge spike in these attempts by obviously unwanted hosts (lots of them from .pl). If I understood my research correctly, the need to whitelist hosts is to keep somebody else from pretending to be my site, and thus jacking login information from users, and I get an error email whenever somebody gets blocked from hosting the site.
Basically, I believe that the need to whitelist hosts is protecting me and my users here. But this sudden spike in unwanted host attempts is worrying.

What can I do about this? Does this call for some sort of reaction on my part (I have no idea what that would be), or does this just mean that the various bots around the internet finally found my little site? I currently am seeing no ill effects, other than that all these requests are driving up my usage on AWS (though not to an insane degree, yet).
There isn't any sensitive information on the site or in its database (I made sure to have everyone create unique passwords for the site, specifically because I'm new to this), other than that it's linked to my AWS account, which obviously has a credit card. There aren't any suspicious charges on the aws account, and the monitoring services show activity on the site, a couple hundred requests in the last few hours (there normally wouldn't be any at this time). Nothing crazy here - average in/out activity between 100 and 200KB, but there should be near 0 activity right now, as no legitimate users are on the site. I'm looking at the actual logs now, and will post if I find anything suspicious there or in response to questions.

Please, this was my first django project, my first web app, etc. I'm out of my depth when things start to go haywire here, I really don't even know if this is an actual problem or SOP.

EDIT -

I'm seeing weird entries in the httpd access log. I'm not sure what it is, but there's scattered entries like

```
172.31.46.155 - - [29/May/2014:03:52:51 +0000] "GET /imp?type(inv)g(17640396)a(2402439)        HTTP/1.1" 400 26 "http://www.klubpodroznika.ibiz.cc/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)"
```

There's also some action in the supervisord.log, but I have no idea if this is unusual. Its a couple days old, so probably irrelevant? In the space of about five seconds, there are entries for:

```
2014-05-27 16:15:47,376 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-05-27 16:15:47,445 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-05-27 16:15:47,445 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-05-27 16:15:47,445 INFO supervisord started with pid 2343
2014-05-27 16:15:48,451 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 2346
2014-05-27 16:15:49,455 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-05-27 16:15:50,648 INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)
2014-05-27 16:15:51,661 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 2379
2014-05-27 16:15:52,664 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of normal. There are a lot of robots on the web dedicated to find vulnerabilities on websites by spoofing headers. Your site is one of the target but hopefully Django has no security flaw usable (at least no known flaws, we are never sure...)

You can't really do anything about it. You could `iptables` or ban IP in some other way to stop them to try to spoof, but it would not be efficient (usually, it is done by zombie machines network, so...).

If mails are annoying you, you [can skip them in Django 1.5](http://www.tiwoc.de/blog/2013/03/django-prevent-email-notification-on-suspiciousoperation/) (in 1.6, the handle of `SuspiciousOperation` is different so it is easier to filter them natively):

```
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation


def skip_suspicious_operations(record):
    if record.exc_info:
        exc_value = record.exc_info[1]
        if isinstance(exc_value, SuspiciousOperation):
            return False
    return True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        # Define filter
        'skip_suspicious_operations': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': skip_suspicious_operations,
        },
    },

# ...
```

... or forbid requests from non-correct HTTP headers before Django, on the webserver (nginx/apache/...)